# Slow process of realtime video over AJAX API

Tags: javascript, ajax, tensorflow, opencv, flask

I am doing a machine learning project. Which works in real-time. I need to send the video from the webcam to a specific API(flask) and show it to the user again(after prediction).

When using the following POST method it's really very slow in localhost.

**CODE 1**

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 320;
canvas.height = 240;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = document.getElementById('image');

if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;

        window.setInterval(function() {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240); 
            canvas.toBlob(upload, "image/jpeg");
        }, 100);    
    });
}

function upload(file) {
    var formdata =  new FormData();
    formdata.append("snap", file);
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost:5000/vid"
    xhr.open("POST", url , true);

    xhr.responseType = 'blob';   
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(this.status = 200) {
        } else {
            console.error(xhr);
        }
        
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
    };
    xhr.send(formdata);
}
```

But when using the direct **cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)** without API posting its working properly.

Any solutions?

**EDIT**
(flask backend part)

```
def send_file_data(data, mimetype='image/jpeg', filename='output.jpg'):
    response = make_response(data)
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', mimetype)
    response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
    
    return response


#predicting result
def generate_frames(frame):

    img_face = cv2.resize(frame,(256,256))    
    
    ** prediction process **
            
    ret,buffer=cv2.imencode('.jpg',img_face)

    frame=buffer.tobytes()

    return frame


#calling this from frontend   
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        fs = request.files.get('snap')
        if fs:
            img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(fs.read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            img = np.array(img)
            return send_file_data(generate_frames(img))
        else:
            return 'ERROR'
    
    return 'WELCOME'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "really slow"? Are you trying to do this for every frame of the video? Have you tested how long posting to that URL alone takes using CURL or Postman? It may just be a slow returning url?

Comment: @JerSchneid Yes! I am trying every frame (as I am predicting with ML model). Really slow means about 3-4 fps. I didn't try with portman because I need to do real-time video. I updated the question( EDIT part ). Any idea?

Comment: "It may just be a slow returning URL?" but how to overcome this issue ?